# What should I transfer to a new computer from iOS project?

Tags: ios, file-transfer

I have been developing an iOS app on my MacBook Air, and now I have to switch to another one.
My question is - what should I transfer?
I will transfer all the project files (.m, .h) but is there something important that I can forget? Like keys for uploading to the appstore or else?

I dont want to transfer, sell the old Mac and then to find out that I have forgoten something important and I will have to recreate the whole project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your projects:

- Copy the whole project folder.

For your provisioning profiles and certificates:

- If you have access to the Apple developer account where you got the provisioning profiles and certificate, then you don't need to export them from your old mac, rather just download them from your iOS Provisioning Portal(login to your developer account in https://developer.apple.com/) then install them in your new mac. Otherwise, export your existing provisioning profiles. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW5), it may be helpful.

If you are selling your old mac:

- You may want to delete the keys, certificates, provisioning and saved usernames and passwords before you hand it to the owner. You may access them through Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access. In the leftside panel, browse through the items and see what you can delete. You can choose to export the items if you opt for it.

Answer (score 0):

From the XCode organiser you'll want to export your developer profile and then import that into the XCode on your new Mac. Take a look [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57059/how-do-i-transfer-my-ios-developer-profile-to-another-computer)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special keys involved with your project other than your developer provisioning profile and your distribution profile if you already made one. If you already downloaded them to your new machine from developers site then just copy the project file from wherever in your system you have stored it to the new machine. Start your xcode and you should be good to go. Check the organizer in xcode to make sure your profiles are updated to the new machine. Just that.